# How to put the end points with the same rows as the start points using shortest path tool on network roads - QGIS?

Tags: qgis, network, batch, shortest-path, qgis-expression

I have 2 point layers containing XY in qgis and I'm trying to get the shortest paths between each rows along a given network (row1 in first layer to row1 in second layer and so on). I used this expression which I added in the batch of the tool - autofill bar:

start point - `aggregate ( 'first layer', 'array_agg', $geometry)`

end point - `aggregate ( 'second layer', 'array_agg', $geometry)`

the problem is that it adds the end point as additional rows (see picture below).
How do I making it to put the end points in the correct rows?

[image: 1]

Comment: Cant you just use layer to point instead, and have the start point as "first layer" then the end point as "end point - aggregate ( 'second layer', 'array_agg', $geometry)"

Would stop that from happening.

Comment: In this stage I get a path layers as the number of points. The problem is that each path layer has an attribute contains in it cost column (Distance) for each path measured for points (attributes with rows as the number of points). For example if tested 5 points I get 5 path layer which has in it 5 rows (one rows for each point). Sums it up, I have now 25 lines describing the paths with different value in it, so I have difficulties to find the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the feature id is the 1-1 relation between start and end points use this.

Use this expression to calculate the **Start point** column. Fill down with the **Add Values by Expression…** option.

```
aggregate(
    'first layer',
    'array_agg',
    $geometry,
    order_by:=$id
)
```

Then select the network layer in the **Vector layer representing network** column and use the **Fill Down** option to fill all the rows with the same layer.

Then calculate the **End point** column with this expression. Fill down using the **Calculate by Expression…** option.

```
aggregate(
    'first layer',
    'array_agg',
    $geometry,
    order_by:=$id
)[@row_number]
```

Comment: Exactly!! Thank you